# Flutter SafeArea

Tags: flutter, layout, widget, safearea

I am new to flutter and I was wondering if there is any way to only get the padding values of the **SafeArea Widget** without using it.
I only want some of my widgets to be affected by the padding and a complete SafeArea widget seems to overcomplicate everything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use this: MediaQuery.of(context).padding. Be Sure you have called on top calls of main this WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()

Comment: But wouldn't I have to use SafeArea in the code for the mediaquery to have the padding?

Comment: No, you have not the necessity to use anything. SafeArea is based on that padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaQuery with viewPadding do the trick, by using

```
MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding
```

you can get padding informations (like app bar size...),
you can also check [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-flutter-guide-to-visual-overlap-padding-viewpadding-and-viewinsets-a63e214be6e8) medium article.